URL Encoding Issue in Redirects with $request_uri
I'm encountering an issue with URL encoding in my Nginx configuration. I have set up a list of redirects using the map directive with $request_uri
map $request_uri $staticRequestRedirect {
    /oil/%F6l_d%FCsseldorf_e2.php /oil/düsseldorf/;
}

The problem is that the redirected URL ends up incorrectly encoded. The URL /oil/%F6l_d%FCsseldorf_e2.php gets redirected to /oil/dÃ¼sseldorf/ instead of /oil/düsseldorf/, resulting in a 404 error.
I'm new to Nginx. It seems to be an issue with character encoding. The source URL contains URL-encoded characters (%F6 for "ö" and %FC for "ü"), but the target URL uses UTF-8 characters directly. This mismatch seems to be causing the problem.
If I unregister the service worker, the redirection works correctly. However, in my case, I cannot unregister the service worker and need to fix this issue through the Nginx configuration.
